# Number of elements in an integer array which is not equal to its size

Tags: c++, arrays

Any ideas..?
For example,

```
int a[50],b;  // b is for getting the input Yes or maybe no 
while(b=='Y')
{cin>>a[i];i++;cin>>b;}
```

and say the user has entered 25 elements.Now i have to use a function which should take **only** the array and the size as parameters...
how will i calculate the number of elements entered by the user inside the function..?
The output should be in this case, 25.

Comment: witthout a sentinel value, you simply cannot.

Comment: How did you insert the values if you do not know the actual index?

Comment: Hey using a while loop!.. like till the input is yes the user can provide values...@mch

Comment: Can you post the while loop code also?

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++?

Comment: Without a counter variable , how can you store the values the user enters? In `a[0]` or `a[1]` or what? Can you give the code of the loop?

Comment: See , i have to use a function which takes only array and size as parameters

Comment: After your `while` loop, the number of integers entered by the user will be in the variables named  `i`.  Pass the array `a` and the count `i` to your other function.  (Don't change `i` in between.)

Comment: yes ik... But i thought there is something like strlen for int arrays with which we can calculate the no of elements entered (without passing i to the udf) which seems impossible

Comment: It is impossible, as the answers say, unless you use a class that implements that feature.  The `strlen` function looks for a sentinel element in the array (the `null` or `'\0'` character) to mark the end of the string.

Comment: Yep..thanks ! @MikeofSST

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `std::list` or `std::vector` for this purposes.

Comment: The question has the `C` language tag.  Some of us have to spin our own lists and vectors.  :-)

Comment: It looks like the `C` tag has been removed, so I guess C++ containers are a valid answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You would be best using a counter variable along with the user input that increments with each entry. Then you just have to loop through that many indexes in the array

```
int counter = 0;
int a[50];

// collect input, counter++ each time

for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    cout << a[i];
```

You would be much better off using a vector. They size automatically so you vcan just print the entire thing using it's included size() function

Comment: Well then it's impossible to achieve this task with an array. Why not just implement a counter?

Comment: ..and how can you loop through the array? Using pointers? Post your code

Comment: With a for loop. You have to be mad to use pointers to print array contents

Comment: @Akilesh: It appears that you don't understand **your** code. There clearly is a counter (which you called `i`). Besides, an array index should be of type `size_t`, not `int`. The differences are subtle, but when the undesired effects kick in, you're wasting hours of your life trying to figure out, what's wrong.

Comment: Dont say that i dont understand my code just because of the down votes! i am clear with my question...i know there is a 'i' in it and thats just for the input part...Now i understood that the no of elements entered cant be counted (in a function which doesnt take i as its parameter) without a sentinel value...@IInspectable

Answer (score -1):

Calculate the number of array elements using counter variable.

For example :

Here array size is `50`, but number of elements is `10`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,cnt = 0; 
    int arr[50] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    for (i = 0; arr[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        cnt++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",cnt);
}
```